# HOW TO select where index LARAVEL API JSON

Tags: json, laravel, api, rest

> **How to echo the second array value where the array index of Json is same as the clicked select option?**

what i need is, when i select the select option that has subject value : Webinar 1, then the  will show the total_participation : 100

**The API Json**

```
 {
      "status": 200,
      "message": "success",
      "data": {
        "records": [
          {
            "subject": "Webinar 1",
            "total_participant": 100
          },
          {
            "subject": "Webinar 2",
            "total_participant": 165
          },
          {
            "subject": "Webinar 3",
            "total_participant": 143
          }
        ]
      },
      "error": []
    }
```

**MY CONTROLLER :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Utils\Endpoints\WebinarEndpoints;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class WebinarController extends Controller
{

    public $webinarEndpoints;

    function __construct(){
        $this->webinarEndpoints = new WebinarEndpoints;
    }
    
    public function index(){
        $result = $this->webinarEndpoints->participant()->json();
        $webinarlist = $this->webinarEndpoints->webinarlist()->json();
        
            switch ($result['status']) {
                case '200':
                    return view('webinar', [
                        'participants' => $result['data']['records'],
                        'lists' => $webinarlist['data']['records']
                    ]);
                    break;
                default : 
                    break;
            }
        
    }

}
```

**VIEW :**

```
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        @foreach ($lists as $list)
        <option onclick="total()">{{$list['subject']}} </option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  
      
    <h3> {{ GET total_participant based on Selected select option index }} </h3>
```

**THANKS FOR HELPING ME!!**

Comment: show what you have tried! also this question might be related to js.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to deal with this could be to give the total_participant to your total() function :

```
<div class="col-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        @foreach ($lists as $list)
        <option onclick="total({{$list['total_participant']}})">{{$list['subject']}} </option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  
      
    <h3> {{ GET total_participant based on Selected select option index }} </h3>
```